# LDAP Authentication on Apache denies valid credentials

Tags: ldap, svn, apache-2.4

I'm trying to link my LDAP with an Apache 2.4 server dedicated to my SVN repositories, so I use the Apache mods *dav_svn* and *authnz_ldap*. The LDAP works properly on its own.

I could manage to bind the server with an admin DN, and search for the user I need.

When connecting, if the user doesn't exist, it is a [No such object] error (yay !). However, if the user exists, the LDAP always returns an [Invalid credentials] error, even if the password is correct.

Here is the Apache error.log end

```
[authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9243:tid 2990508864] mod_authnz_ldap.c(516): [client ::1:46639] AH01691:
auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr?uid?sub

[ldap:debug] [pid 9243:tid 2990508864] util_ldap.c(379): AH01278: 
LDAP: Setting referrals to On.

[authnz_ldap:info] [pid 9243:tid 2990508864] [client ::1:46639] AH01695:
auth_ldap authenticate: user mr.myself authentication failed; URI /svn/ [ldap_simple_bind() to check user credentials failed][Invalid credentials]

[auth_basic:error] [pid 9243:tid 2990508864] [client ::1:46639] AH01617:
user mr.myself: authentication failure for "/svn/": Password Mismatch
```

And here is my config file

```
<VirtualHost domain:443>
    ServerName domain
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ssl/key.pem
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

    <Location /svn>
        DAV                 svn
        SVNParentPath       /path/to/svn/repositories
        SVNListParentPath   ON

        AuthType            Basic
        AuthName            "a nice message"

        AuthBasicProvider   ldap
        AuthLDAPURL         ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr?uid?sub
        AuthLDAPBindDN      cn=mr-admin,ou=cccc,ou=bbbb,dc=company,dc=fr
        AuthLDAPBindPassword clear_password

        <RequireAll>
            Require         valid-user
            Require         ssl
            Require         ldap-group cn=svngroup,ou=ffff,ou=eeee,ou=dddd,dc=company,dc=fr
        </RequireAll>
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The only config I added to Apache besides this file is "**Listen 443**" in ports.conf

Do you have any idea about what the problem is ? I've been searching for a while now, and I need this working soon.

Thanks for reading (and sorry for that bad english)

------- Edit : additional details

- This is my whole code
- I only changed the domain, paths, DN names, and bindDN password for clarity.
- I have the same result when changing `uid` into `cn`
- Here are the ldapsearch results

.

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ -D cn=mr.myself,ou=gggg,ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr -w 'p4(sSwo]rd' -v 
ldap_initialize( ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/??base ) 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49) 

ldapsearch -x -H ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ -D cn=mr.myself,ou=gggg,ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr -w p4(sSwo]rd -v 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token "("
```

Comment: What's the dn of your users? Also dumping the traffic would be very useful in understanding what's wrong, especially since you're not encrypting anything between ldap and apache. What directory server are you using?

Comment: @stoned The user DN is something like "cn=mr.myself,ou=gggg,ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr"

Comment: try replacing `uid` in `ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr?uid?sub` with `cn`. Can you make a dump of the communication between apache and ldap?
Also, is that your real code, or did you skip pieces with different authentication parts?

Comment: @stoned This is my whole code, I only changed the domain, paths, DN names, and bindDN password for clarity. I have the same result when changing `uid` into `cn`

Comment: I tried using `mod_dumpio`, but nothing more appears between `auth_ldap authenticate : using URL ldap://....` and `[Invalid credentials]`

Comment: Found this when the browser is sending the authentication request : `[dumpio:trace7] [pid 14653:tid 2940152640] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ::1:51882] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-TRANSIENT): Authorization: Basic some_encrypted_key_here\r\n`, is it possible that the password is encrypted when sent to the LDAP while it shouldn't ?

Comment: There should be no encryption, it's not ldaps and apache doesn't support sasl for ldap auth anyway. Are you on linux? use `tcpdump -i <your_net_interface to the ldap server> -vv -nn -s0 'host <your_ldap_server>' -w /tmp/dump.cap` then open the cap file with wireshark. Check for the ldap initial bind request, what is it sending?

Comment: If I read that well, Apache first sends the bindDN and password, which are validated by the LDAP. Then, Apache sends the search for the user mr.myself, which is answered by the LDAP with that user's DN. Then Apache sends the user's DN and the password, but the LDAP doesn't validate it

Comment: Is the second pass with a clear text password as well? Have you checked that you can correctly bind to the ldap server as that user through any client?

Comment: The password is clear text. The user should work since it is used by other clients (like the company's e-mail system) and I can connect on those just fine.

Comment: As a test, if you're on linux, can you try running `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://my_ldap_ip:port -D "<full dn of your user here, as returned by the ldap search>"  -w <plain text password>

Comment: LDAPLibraryDebug might give a hint about why your SDK chooses that return code., as a complement to the packet capture.

Comment: @stoned Is it possible for a password to have parenthesis or brackets ?

Comment: Hi @Irhala yes, you can have any character. Did you manage to bind your user whith the ldapsearch command? ldapsearch is very useful as a test tool when something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I got this : `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ -D cn=mr.myself,ou=gggg,ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr -w 'p4(sSwo]rd' -v `  
`ldap_initialize( ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/??base )`  
`ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`  
`ldapsearch -x -H ldap://my_ldap_ip:port/ -D cn=mr.myself,ou=gggg,ou=aaaa,dc=company,dc=fr -w p4(sSwo]rd -v `  
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token "(" `

Comment: I put it above, can't really read it here

Comment: @stoned I guess I'll have to check with the LDAP admins, I have no idea why this doesn't work

Comment: @Irhala remove `-w <password>` and use `-W`, that will ask you for the password interactively. And remove the trailing `/`after the port number in the `-H` option. Still invalid credentials?

Comment: Same thing, still invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

This is a valid configuration, the problem was located in our LDAP. I had my password reset and everything works fine.